# Ho to get all products by title and categories it belong to

Tags: mongodb

I would like to get all products and categories it belong to.
I have this full text search query
[sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aqpe5cLlYGO7JZlXV-MhgEHKSJXT8eb-dLvUEO2c_9E/edit?usp=sharing)

```
db.products.find(
{ $text: { $search: 'IPhone 6' } },
{ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
.sort({ score:{$meta: "textScore" } })
.limit(100)
```

It gives me all the products and it's main and sub categories, but since we have a limit Frontend is not able to show all the main and sub categories

Somehow I need to add distinct main and sub categories

Looks like aggregation is a way to go but I can not figure out how to do it.

Would be grateful for any help!

I expect output to be like this

```
{
        "main_category_name": "Lights & Lighting",
        "main_category_id": 39,
        "sub_categories": [
            {
                "sub_сategory_name_1": "Portable Lighting",
                "sub_сategory_id_1": 390503,
                "sub_сategory_name_2": [
                    {
                        "sub_сategory_name_2": "Flashlights & Torches",
                        "sub_сategory_id_2": 150410,
                        "sub_сategory_name_3": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but it gets really gnarly after 3 layers - I'd probably recommend a schema change, or possibly just getting the distinct values and re-structuring them at the app layer, that being said - it is possible:

```
db.test1.aggregate([{
   $group: { _id: {
     main_category_name: "$main_category_name",
     main_category_id: "$main_category_id",
     sub_category_name_1: "$sub_category_name_1",
     sub_category_id_1: "$sub_category_id_1",
     sub_category_name_2: "$sub_category_name_2",
     sub_category_id_2: "$sub_category_id_2",
   },
   sub_categories: { $addToSet: { sub_category_name_3: "$sub_category_name_3", sub_category_id_3: "$sub_category_id_3" } }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
     main_category_name: "$_id.main_category_name",
     main_category_id: "$_id.main_category_id",
     sub_category_name_1: "$_id.sub_category_name_1",
     sub_category_id_1: "$_id.sub_category_id_1",
   },
   sub_categories: {
     $addToSet: {
       sub_category_id_2: "$_id.sub_category_id_2",
       sub_category_name_2: "$_id.sub_category_name_2",
       sub_categories: "$sub_categories"
     }
   }
 }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
     main_category_name: "$_id.main_category_name",
     main_category_id: "$_id.main_category_id",
   },
   sub_categories: {
     $addToSet: {
       sub_category_id_1: "$_id.sub_category_id_1",
       sub_category_name_1: "$_id.sub_category_name_1",
       sub_categories: "$sub_categories"
     }
   }
 }
}

])
```

Couple small things:

1. It wasn't clear what naming convention you wanted (`sub_categories` vs `sub_category_name_n`) - so I kept it consistent at `sub_categories`
2. Every aggregation pipeline needs an `_id` - so your `main_category_name` and `main_category_id` got pushed in.

The result is:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "main_category_name" : "test",
        "main_category_id" : 1
    },
    "sub_categories" : [
        {
            "sub_category_id_1" : 2,
            "sub_category_name_1" : "test 1",
            "sub_categories" : [
                {
                    "sub_category_id_2" : 2,
                    "sub_category_name_2" : "test 2",
                    "sub_categories" : [
                        {
                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "sub_category_id_1" : 3,
            "sub_category_name_1" : "test 3",
            "sub_categories" : [
                {
                    "sub_category_id_2" : 5,
                    "sub_category_name_2" : "test 5",
                    "sub_categories" : [
                        {
                            
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "sub_category_id_2" : 4,
                    "sub_category_name_2" : "test 4",
                    "sub_categories" : [
                        {
                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Note the `{}` in the final layer is because my dummy data didn't have `sub_category_*_3` fields - if you need to filter these out, you can do so easily at the app layer (it would be possible with an aggregation stage too)

Comment: Zack, thank you for help!
It's almost what I was expecting, my first question was not complete.

I have updated it with expected output. Would be grateful if you can update your query to have output I added to the question

Comment: Zack, one more time thank you for help! How would you recommend to change the schema?

Idea is to show show products with categories it belongs to. 

We now use Mongo and did index for product_title_en, so user can do search by title and see products, would be nice also to show categories with this products to narrow down the search

Comment: here is sample data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aqpe5cLlYGO7JZlXV-MhgEHKSJXT8eb-dLvUEO2c_9E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: If I will change db structure like this, just categories =

"Sports & Entertainment\Musical Instruments\Electric Instrument\Electric Instrument Parts & Accessories"

I am interested in query where I will have .limt(50) and also I need to give all the categories back to UI so they will show all the categories where we have this product

Comment: output should be like this

    products: [{}...50],
    categories: ["Consumer Electronics\Power Source\Solar\Solar Accessories", "Sports & Entertainment\Musical Instruments\Household Chemicals\Household Chemicals"]

If you have a better idea, you are welcome to suggest

Comment: While you may choose to de-normalize data like this, I'd probably have a collection of categories with their sub categories (e.g., a collection of documents stored just like the result you want). I'd then filter that result either on the client or server, not in the DB. You're not really saving anything by doing it with an aggregation, just offloading work to the DB

Comment: I am thinking about 1 query to db  just to have a quick response
also thinking now about next output

{
  Products [array of products here],
 Categories [ 
{"Sport", "sub_category_1","sub_category_2","sub_category_3"},
{"Home", "sub_category_1","sub_category_2","sub_category_3"},
"Phones", "sub_category_1","sub_category_2","sub_category_3"
]
}

can you help with such query?